# How to get array of image files on /DCIM/Camera?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get the images in the default images location and print the file name into a TextView.

When I try to get to the directory, I always get a nullpointerexception on  `listFiles`. I've tried a few ways to get the directory path, but nothing seems to work.

I've even setup the permission in the manifest. 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final String NEW_LINE = "\n";

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.renameImgBtn);
    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            File camDir = new File("/sdcard/DCIM/"); // wtf is this supposed to be!?

            textView.append(camDir.getAbsolutePath() + NEW_LINE);
            if (camDir == null) {
                textView.append("camDir is null" + NEW_LINE);
            } else {
                textView.append("camDir is not null" + NEW_LINE);

                // get nullpointerexception on listFiles
                File[] files = camDir.listFiles();
                if (files == null) {
                    textView.append("files is null" + NEW_LINE);
                } else {
                    for (final File file : files) {
                        textView.append(file.getName() + NEW_LINE);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I'm using a Nexus 6P and the images are under DCIM/Camera/.

Comment: Use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)`.

Comment: @MikeM. Yes, I've tried that. Same result.

Comment: Can you use camDir.exists() to check exist and do you has folder named DCIM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the DCIM directory is defined by [DIRECTORY_DCIM](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_DCIM) and should be used in conjuction with [Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)):

```
File camDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
    Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
```

Secondly, as you are on a Marshmallow device, if you target API 23, you must [request dangerous permissions at runtime](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) - `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is a dangerous permission and falls under those rules.

Answer (score 0):

can you use

```
File camDir = new File("/sdcard0/DCIM/");
```

or

```
File camDir = new File("/sdcard1/DCIM/");
```

and check if the file is not null and exits true.